# How to pull the substrings in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset like below and I want to pull the first name and last name from my variable.

```
data

   variable
1  "STEPHEN GIRARD CAREY, DO                "
2  "BRADLEY B. WILLIAMS, M.D.               "
3  "MICHAEL F. DILLARD, MD                  "
4  "MICHAEL S HOLMAN, MD                    "
5  "LIEN DUC NGUYEN, M.D.                   "
6  "GIRIDHAR GUNDU, MD                      "
7  "CHRISTOPHER LEE KELLY, PA-C             "
8  "JENNIFER L. FLETCHER, DO                "
9  "JOHN S KABAS MD                         "
10 "ELIZABETH CLENTERA SMITH DO, MPH        "
11 "ALLAN JAMES THOMPSON, JR, MD            "
12 "LAWERENCE KEVIN O'MALLEY II, M.D.       "
13 "STEPHEN GIRARD CAREY, DO                "
14 "KELLY, MD, WILLIAM/MTS                  "
15 "MICHAEL GRANT AVANT                     "
16 "NICHOLAS DEMITRI PAPPAS III, M.D.       "
```

From the above data set I want to pull the first name and the last name and I want to assign those to new variable names

Expected Output:

```
data

    variable                                        first_name       last_name
1  "STEPHEN GIRARD CAREY, DO                "      STEPHEN          CAREY
2  "BRADLEY B. WILLIAMS, M.D.               "      BRADLEY          WILLIAMS
3  "MICHAEL F. DILLARD, MD                  "      MICHAEL          DILLARD
4  "MICHAEL S HOLMAN, MD                    "      MICHAEL          HOLMAN
5  "LIEN DUC NGUYEN, M.D.                   "      LIEN             NGUYEN
6  "GIRIDHAR GUNDU, MD                      "      GIRIDHAR         GUNDU
7  "CHRISTOPHER LEE KELLY, PA-C             "      CHRISTOPHER      KELLY
8  "JENNIFER L. FLETCHER, DO                "      JENNIFER         FLETCHER
9  "JOHN S KABAS MD                         "      JOHN             KABAS
10 "ELIZABETH CLENTERA SMITH DO, MPH        "      ELIZABETH        SMITH
11 "ALLAN JAMES THOMPSON, JR, MD            "      ALLAN            THOMPSON
12 "LAWERENCE KEVIN O'MALLEY II, M.D.       "      LAWERENCE        O'MALLEY
13 "STEPHEN GIRARD CAREY, DO                "      STEPHEN          CAREY
14 "KELLY, MD, WILLIAM/MTS                  "      KELLY            WILLIAM/MTS
15 "MICHAEL GRANT AVANT                     "      MICHAEL          AVANT
16 "NICHOLAS DEMITRI PAPPAS III, M.D.       "      NICHOLAS         PAPPAS
```

I have tried:

```
library(plyr)  

data$first_name <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(data$variable)," "), "[", 1)  
data$last_name <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(data$variable)," "), "[", 2)
```

From the above I am able to pull the first name but I am not able to pull the last, please help me on this.

Comment: `"^\\S+|\\S+(?=,[^,]*$)"`

Comment: @Avinash Raj, thanks for the quick reply but what the above command will do?

Comment: Your task is impossible. The strings in your dataset don't have a regular form and thus cannot be parsed by any regular language or algorithm.

Comment: Absolutely. Your string is not consistent. For eg: Row 14: Kelly. When you get the first name out, im sure you're extracting the "," in the name too.

Comment: I agree with @kliron and @MaxPD . Try standardizing the strings before extraction, I'd `gsub` all the titles (MD, M.D, ...) and all the numeric(II, III, ... ) with empty string. I'd also remove the single characters (`strsplit` over space and dot, then check the `nchar`). Then take the first word and the last word before the comma.

Comment: @Deena it would still be hopeless i think. The number of tokens and the token form in each row is almost completely unstructured, excluding first name. The only way to extract last name is to tokenize on space and then use a heuristic algorithm like "excluding all latin numbers, titles like MD, M.D., King, JR, Grand Vizier, and so on, get the longest remaining string". Not fool-proof and very expensive though - if that sort of thing matters.

Answer (score 0):

The following is very specific to the names provided in the question, so I would not use it for every case you may have that is not shown here:

```
crazynames <- c("STEPHEN GIRARD CAREY, DO ", 
          "BRADLEY B. WILLIAMS, M.D.", 
          "MICHAEL F. DILLARD, MD", 
          "MICHAEL S HOLMAN, MD", 
          "LIEN DUC NGUYEN, M.D.", 
          "GIRIDHAR GUNDU, MD", 
          "CHRISTOPHER LEE KELLY, PA-C", 
          "JENNIFER L. FLETCHER, DO", 
          "JOHN S KABAS MD", 
          "ELIZABETH CLENTERA SMITH DO, MPH", 
          "ALLAN JAMES THOMPSON, JR, MD", 
          "LAWERENCE KEVIN O'MALLEY II, M.D.", 
          "STEPHEN GIRARD CAREY, DO ", 
          "KELLY, MD, WILLIAM/MTS", 
          "MICHAEL GRANT AVANT", 
          "NICHOLAS DEMITRI PAPPAS III, M.D.")

crazynames <- as.data.frame(crazynames)
crazynames$firstname <- NULL
crazynames$lastname <- NULL

crazynames$firstname <- lapply(crazynames$crazynames, function(r) {
  return(unlist(strsplit(trimws(gsub("MD|M.D.|II|[^A-Za-z /']|DO|MPH|PA-C|JR|III","",r))," "))[1])
  })
crazynames$lastname <- lapply(crazynames$crazynames, function(r) {
  fullname <- unlist(strsplit(trimws(gsub("MD|M.D.|II|[^A-Za-z /']|DO|MPH|PA-C|JR|III","",r))," "))
  if(length(fullname) < 3) return(fullname[2])
  if(length(fullname)>=3) return(fullname[length(fullname)])
})

crazynames

                                 crazynames   firstname    lastname
1  STEPHEN GIRARD CAREY, DO                     STEPHEN       CAREY
2  BRADLEY B. WILLIAMS, M.D.                    BRADLEY    WILLIAMS
3  MICHAEL F. DILLARD, MD                       MICHAEL     DILLARD
4  MICHAEL S HOLMAN, MD                         MICHAEL      HOLMAN
5  LIEN DUC NGUYEN, M.D.                           LIEN      NGUYEN
6  GIRIDHAR GUNDU, MD                          GIRIDHAR       GUNDU
7  CHRISTOPHER LEE KELLY, PA-C              CHRISTOPHER       KELLY
8  JENNIFER L. FLETCHER, DO                    JENNIFER    FLETCHER
9  JOHN S KABAS MD                                 JOHN       KABAS
10 ELIZABETH CLENTERA SMITH DO, MPH           ELIZABETH       SMITH
11 ALLAN JAMES THOMPSON, JR, MD                   ALLAN    THOMPSON
12 LAWERENCE KEVIN O'MALLEY II, M.D.          LAWERENCE    O'MALLEY
13 STEPHEN GIRARD CAREY, DO                     STEPHEN       CAREY
14 KELLY, MD, WILLIAM/MTS                         KELLY WILLIAM/MTS
15 MICHAEL GRANT AVANT                          MICHAEL       AVANT
16 NICHOLAS DEMITRI PAPPAS III, M.D.           NICHOLAS      PAPPAS
```

The first four lines are self explanatory, so I am going to move on the `lapply()` chunks.  What I did here is remove any qualification along with anything that is not a letter or apostrophes (`gsub("MD|M.D.|II|[^A-Za-z /']|DO|MPH|PA-C|JR|III","",r)`) part. Once that is done, then I trimmed the white spaces with `trimws()` and applied the `strsplit()` function to get the first and last names.

I hope this provides you with a solid starting point.

Comment: thanks for answering ,this is actually great ,but the problem is if we include LL in gsub and variable is say.. ANDREW NELL. the above commands will remove LL from ANDREW NE (ANDREW NELL). this is not what i want...

Comment: @ashok, it is actually not LL but rather II (two capitalized i's). It is a suffix appended to quite a few names; basically the same thing as first, second, third. But I see the point you are making: for example the "DO" character could cause a lot of problems because "DO" is a very common succession of letters in names. What I would do here is extract the first name without `gsub()` and then play around safely with the last name to make sure that you're only removing suffixes after the third comma.

Answer (score -2):

Although you seem to have a large amount of variation in the formatting of your names, would it be worth implementing an algorithm that worked for most of them e.g.

```
library(stringr)
name <- "James Bond, 007"
if(str_detect(name, ", ")) {
  name <- strsplit(name, ", ")[[1]]
  if(length(name) > 2) {
    last_name <- word(name[length(name)], -1)
  } else {
    last_name <- word(name[1], -1)
  }
}
first_name <- word(name[1], 1)
```

And then hand checking the remainder, in this case those without any commas separating out the qualifications? Otherwise the only way would be to have an exhaustive list of possible qualifications but even this might not be fool proof as you might have "BROWN MD" where no algorithm could decide

Comment: my question is entirely different , even i knew what you have done, but your answer won't solve my issue.